# Django JSONDecodeError at ...= get_response(request)

Tags: python, json, django

When i run the server and look at localhost i got this error:

JSONDecodeError at ...Traceback response = get_response(request)

What am i doing wrong?

My Code is :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
import requests


def home(request):
    response = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org')
    data = response.json()
    dump = json.dumps(data)
    return render(request, 'catalog/home.html', {'ip': dump})
```

Comment: That "API" does not seem to return JSON.

Comment: Well it looks like the API is not returning JSON. Perhaps it is returning an XML, CSV, HTML, ... or other formatted stream. `.json(..)` is not a "magic" function, all it aims to do is interpret the response as a JSON stream, and construct the "equivalent" Python object.

Comment: thank you for your fast reaction. I'm new in this and investigate now:   return JsonResponse({"key": "value"})

Comment: i made a request to get an IP-Adress. This works. And now i want to serve this ip in my API for an APP. How can i convert the IP to a Integer? And give this information as json? This is what i try here.

Comment: Just to justify the above comments, remove the `data = response.json()` and just `print(response)` the response to terminal (*if in development*) to understand what is going on there.

Comment: i will try this to see how all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the URL to `https://api.ipify.org?format=json` and your code would work.

Alternatively, you can still use the `https://api.ipify.org` URL, but since it outputs the IP directly, you should skip the JSON parsing and `return render(request, 'catalog/home.html', {'ip': response.content})` instead.

Comment: So now i tried: https://api.ipify.org?format=json and get the Error: InvalidURL at /catalog/ . I also used than return render(request, 'catalog/home.html', {'ip': response.content}) . And get the same error.

Failed to parse: https:

Comment: had this something to do that i have a http and not a https server? And...thank you for your fast reaction!

Comment: You may have a typo somewhere in the URL. Please make sure there isn't an extra space in the URL or something like that.

Comment: Yeah..that was it! Thank you All!... blhsing was right now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! blhsing gave my what i tried to do. Now i got the right format.
The output was with {...} and i got the format like https://www.webforefront.com/static/images/beginningdjango/Figure_12-1.png ... what i need.
i will try this for my other APP.

I will also try this: (with the same adress blhsing gave me and it works too. Only the output changed)
return HttpResponse(dump,content_type='application/json')

...that i can make a GET request with json and the APP knows the format.